# How can I apply notch curve to Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have a design as you can see below and the question is how can I apply this notch effect on Arrow ? Is there any easy way to do it just like in Floating Action Button ? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please can you add your code

Comment: There is no code since I couldn't figure out how to achieve this notch effect. I just need to hear logics and ideas about how to achieve this.

Comment: https://github.com/abdullah0912/flutter_Online_Course_App_UI?ref=flutterawesome.com check this out

Comment: https://github.com/devmuaz/coupon_uikit?ref=flutterawesome.com this might help you

Comment: What you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created Dartpad, please look into this and do let me know if you need any help.

Dartpad Link : https://dartpad.dev/flutter?9bd55396e067e71a839851e18905f478

Code:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 70,
    child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.cyan, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 40,
        height: 65,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 5)),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          child: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
        ),
      )
    ]),
  ),
);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot you solved my problem. I just couldn't understand why you have SizedBox on Stack. Can I ask your logic  ? In my case it worked perfect without that SizedBox.

Comment: Yeah nice question. Its just because I wanted to give some static height.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can achieve it in 2 way

1st one and simple - Create a `box decoration` widget and a `circle shape` widget with white border and put these together with `Stack` and fit as per your requirements.

2nd use [Custom Clipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html) or [Custom Paint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) and draw your shape.